# SharePoint 2010 Attachments, display person name who attached the file and the date time

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I have been asked to find and display additional attachment information.  The name of the person who attached the file and the date and time the file was attached. Is this data available for each attachments ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no such (person who attached the file and the date and time) fields. SharePoint considers that the attachment is a bundle operation with the item creation or modified,  so it depends on the `Created By` , `Modified By` and `modified date` fields.

So I am also sure that the `modified by` and `modified date` fields will not help you because they will be overwritten after next modify. Also, versioning doesn't show the attachments.

So my suggestion is to do something like this:

- Create `Attachment History List` to save the attachment actions.
- Build workflow on Item created and Item changed on the main list to track if there's an attachment or not by

  - Checking if there's `attachment = Yes`
  - Create an item at `Attachment History List` to save the `modified by` and `modified date` and the ID of the main Item.

[image]

- Now you can link the main list with your `Attachment History List` to track the attachment custom fields.